# A memory-polymorphic slice function in C

Tags: c, memory, polymorphism

Imagine an array_slice method which returns a part of an array. Imagine also that your program is using multiple memory allocation strategies, like Boehm, ref count, pools, alloc/free. Is there an idiomatic or somewhat non-contrived way to do this array_slice function in a way that it's agnostic about the memory allocation?

Small code-snippet for context.

```c
typedef struct array array;
struct array {
    size_t length;
    uintptr_t* thing;
};
array array_slice(array old, int offset)
{
    size_t new_length = old.length - offset;
    array new = {
        .length = new_length,
        // TODO: This line needs to use same allocation strategy as for argument "old"
        .thing = malloc(sizeof(uintptr_t) * new_length)
    };
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = offset; i < old.length; i++) {
        new.thing[j] = old.thing[i];
        j++;
    }
    return new;
}
```

One solution could be for the array struct to carry with it a function pointer and other information. Another maybe using _Generic? Open for suggestions or links. :) Thank you.

One problem is that each memory allocation strategy requires slightly different ceremony around it, like ref count needs to bump or decrease the counter, pools need to pass around a pointer to the used pool object, normal malloc needs to be freed at the correct place.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ehm that's completely unrelated to the question. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Do you have an `array_create` or `array_alloc` function to create the original `old` structure and its allocation? Does it use `malloc` directly, or some kind of wrapper to be able to use different allocation systems? Why can't you use the same code, or indeed just call `array_create` (or what it might be called) to create the `new` array?

Comment: And if you *don't* have any kind of `array_create` (or the like) and the memory is allocated outside of your "array" API, then I would first of all consider that a design flaw; And secondly there's just no way to find out what system was used for the initial allocation, of what `old.thing` might be pointing to. It might not even be dynamically allocated to begin with.

Comment: Are you looking for type-generic way to copy a sub-range of an array?

Comment: Also, a good night sleep might be a good idea... Sometimes that could help solving problems miraculously. ;) Don't burn that midnight oil when you don't need to. Coke, coffee and sleep depravation never really helps. :) It will also give others some time to perhaps find an answer, or at least post some useful comments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I imagine I would have multiple `array_create` functions - one for each memory allocation strategy.

Comment: Then I would suggest you save a pointer to the function in the `array` structure, so it can be reused when needed. And use it to allocate the `new` array in your slice function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, lemme try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic polymorphism, you could define an abstract 'allocator' class:

```
struct Allocator {
    void *(*alloc)(struct Allocator *, size_t);
    void (*dealloc)(struct Allocator *, void *);
}
extern struct Allocator *malloc_allocator;
/* other allocator types here */
```

with an implementation like

```
void *malloc_alloc(struct Allocator *, size_t sz) {
    return malloc(sz);
}
void malloc_dealloc(struct Allocator *, void *ptr) {
    return free(ptr);
}

static struct Allocator malloc_alloc_obj = { malloc_alloc, malloc_dealloc };
struct Allocator *malloc_allocator = &malloc_alloc_obj;
```

You can define other allocator types similarly -- those that need extra data cn define a private struct that begins with a `struct Allocator` field and has the extra data following.  Then you just need to add a pointer to your `struct Array`.

C does not provide good ways of doing static polymorphism.  You can fake it with macros, but the result is pretty fragile.

Comment: Hm, how would this work in combination with the proposed array_slice function?

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine an array_slice method which returns a part of an array

You may be using the wrong abstraction here. Do *all* the users of `array` actually need to own a copy of the elements in the slice?

Separating the "slicing" from copying and ownership of the underlying memory would allow you to make and pass around slices very cheaply, and when a copy is actually needed, the owner of that copy can decide which memory allocation strategy is most appropriate for that particular copy.

In `C++`, this light-weight slicing is implemented by the [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) class.

Your `struct array` could remain exactly the same, with the only difference that `thing` points to memory owned by someone else. The `array_slice` becomes much simpler and cheaper:

```
array array_slice(array old, int offset)
{
    assert(offset <= old.length); 
    array new = {
        .length = old.length - offset,
        .thing = old.thing + offset;
    };
    return new;
}
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but your answer is unrelated to my question. The fact that I'm using `array_slice` as an example is incidental - it could be any function that returns a new memory chunk. :) Well, I guess I could have been more clear in that regard by phrasing the question in more general words.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt I think this answer is _very_ related to your question. You chose a particular abstraction and are asking _how_ to implement it. I am saying that abstraction you chose is _possibly_ wrong (i.e. you should take a step back). You are of course free to ignore this advice.